# Detect prefix and/or suffix in python

Tags: python, prefix, suffix

I'm trying to write a program to detect whether a word has a prefix and/or a suffix. Normally, I'd just use `.startswith()` and `.endswith()`. I'd prefer not to use that here because certain words, like 'antique' will get incorrectly interpreted as having a prefix of 'anti', even though that's not what the 'anti' represents.

I've thought about using Machine Learning, but am wondering if that would even be beneficial because I could just use the dataset that I used to train the ML algorithm as a dataset, and just lookup words there.

Are there any workarounds to this? Or do I just have to use a dataset? If so, where can I find such a dataset?

Comment: This sounds like a thing [NLTK](https://nltk.org/) could be useful for, but I am not familiar enough to know if provides exactly what you need.

Comment: Ah, but if you go back far enough (in time), the "anti-" in "antique" *is* a prefix! https://www.etymonline.com/word/antique

Comment: You should be clear about what you mean by prefix and suffix. Expected meaning would make `startswith` and `endswith` valid. You could maybe provide some explanation and samples.

Comment: Many, of not most, English speakers would not be able to make the distinction you're trying to make. So training an AI to do it may be difficult. It seems like you need an Expert System trained by lexicographers.